# JavaScript conditional statements if/else if/else

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, comparator

**Hello guys! Could you please help me out? I am trying to use certain conditions but they seem to be ignored for some reasons. When I ran the code the popped-up random number given was 93 that fitted in the first declared statement (if), but,  It got ignored and moved to the last statement even when true && true.
I do not understand why...
???**

```
function loveMatching (name1, name2) {
    
    name1 = prompt ("Enter your name!");
    name2 = prompt ("Enter your crush name!");

   
 if (matchingPercentage() >= 70 && matchingPercentage() <=100) {

   document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchingPercentage() + "%. You guys are meant to be together!");

  }
  else if( matchingPercentage() >=30 && matchingPercentage() <70) {
    document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchingPercentage() + "%. Too close to fail!");
  }

 else {
  document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchingPercentage() + "%. You better look in another direction!");
 }

  }

function matchingPercentage() {
    var n = Math.random();
    var n = Math.floor(n * 100) + 1;
return n;
}



loveMatching();
```

Comment: Each time you call matchingPercentage() will give you a *different* random number. If you just want one, call it once and save it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

you're calculating a new match % everytime you check it, multiple times in the same conditional. you need to just do it once at the start:

```
function loveMatching (name1, name2) {
    
    name1 = prompt ("Enter your name!");
    name2 = prompt ("Enter your crush name!");
    const matchPercent = matchingPercentage(); // call one time
   
 if (matchPercent >= 70 && matchPercent <=100) {

   document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchPercent + "%. You guys are meant to be together!");

  }
  else if( matchPercent >=30 && matchPercent <70) {
    document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchPercent + "%. Too close to fail!");
  }

 else {
  document.write(" The compability between: " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of a " + matchPercent + "%. You better look in another direction!");
 }

}
```